# Why InvokeRequired property value differed between VS2012 and VS2013?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am developing UI automation for my control. The below code working fine in VS2012.

```
MyControl.PointToClient(p);
```

But this code not working in VS2013. It was throws an following exception
[image]

Also i have used the below code to Invoke the control

```
public new Point PointToClient(Point p)
{
   if (MyControl.InvokeRequired)
   {
       pointToClientCallBack ptcb = new pointToClientCallBack(PointToClient);
       GetWindow().Invoke(ptcb, new object[] { p });
   }
   return MyControl.PointToClient(p);
}
delegate Point pointToClientCallBack(Point p);
```

after i invoked my control, InvokeRequired property is in true.

So, can you please suggest me the right way to solve this problem.

Thanks,

Comment: InvokeRequired is a pretty questionable property, it just adds one more threading race bug to code.  If you have no idea on which thread this code runs then it gets *very* difficult to prove that it is thread-safe.  The race bug occurs when this code runs at the same time as the UI thread is busy creating the control window.  GetWindow() is in itself is already a very good candidate btw, hard to see why you did that.  You'll have to ensure that the thread cannot get started until the UI is ready.  The Load event is the signal.

Comment: @HansPassant, In GetWindow method i return my control. I have found one differentiation between the _VS2012_ and _VS2013_. In _VS2012_, Thread **State** in Running and **IsBackground** property as false. In _VS2013_ Thread state in Background and **IsBackground** property as true. can you please suggest me how to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Well, that happens when you have no idea on what thread your code runs.  You must stop assuming that this is a VS induced problem to get ahead.  Use the debugger, the Call Stack window is important to figure out where the call came from.

Answer (score 1):

> differed between VS2012 and VS2013?

I'm not sure about that, but I do know that you don't `return` after the `Invoke` so afterwards it calls `return MyControl.PointToClient(p);` from the worker thread.

Change:

```
public new Point PointToClient(Point p)
{
   if (MyControl.InvokeRequired)
   {
       pointToClientCallBack ptcb = new pointToClientCallBack(PointToClient);
       GetWindow().Invoke(ptcb, new object[] { p });
   }
   return MyControl.PointToClient(p);
}
```

...to:

```
public new Point PointToClient(Point p)
{
   if (MyControl.InvokeRequired)
   {
       pointToClientCallBack ptcb = new pointToClientCallBack(PointToClient);
       return GetWindow().Invoke(ptcb, new object[] { p }) as Point;
   }
   return MyControl.PointToClient(p);
}
```

Note that we need to convert the object returned from `Invoke` to `Point` to match your method signature.

Also, you probably should use `BeginInvoke` rather than `Invoke` as the latter can lead to *deadlock*.

Comment: If i use the return statement, I need to calculate the point for control using PointToClient method. If i try that without InvokeRequired value as false. It will throws an exception.

Comment: @MOHANRAJG I'm not saying that do so _"without InvokeRequired"_. You should not get an exception with the suggestion above

Comment: thanks for your response.
The method return type is point so need to return the point (pt) to calculate the window co-ordinates.
But it does not calculate the actual point until the InvokeRequired is "True". 
Therefore the else part is need to return the actual value in my case.

**Note:**
Is that any specific reason for this works fine in VS2012 and not in VS2013 until i make the implementation as follows,

'While(MyControl.InvokeRequired)
{
  // repeat the if part 
}

return MyControl.PointToClient(p);'

Bur i don't know what is the major cause.

Comment: oh my bad, one sec

Comment: See updated answer.  No, I don't know why it would have worked in VS12